# Xamarin forms increase ProgressBar height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have been developing a Xamarin forms application. I want to increase the height of the progress bar control. I used custom renders to change the color of the progress control. But I couldn't find any way to increase the height. Please help me. following is my Custom render class.

```cs
public class MyProgressBarRenderer:ProgressBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged (
         ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        Control.ProgressTintColor =  Color.FromHex ("#254f5e").ToUIColor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this override to MyProgressBarRenderer, and adjust Y as necessary....

```
using UIKit; 
using CoreGraphics;
......
public override void LayoutSubviews()
{
   base.LayoutSubviews();

   var X = 1.0f;
   var Y = 5.0f;

   CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(X,Y);
   this.Transform = transform; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: This override doesn't work, doesn't recognise the method

Comment: Are you trying in your Xamarin.iOS project? The OP appeared to be asking specifically for iOS. I just tried it again and it works for iOS.

Comment: Added a screenshot to demonstrate the working code. Don't forget the using statements also.

Comment: Sorry I was asking about Xamarin.Android project, my bad.

Comment: Thank you, man! I was looking for an answer for some while now! Right on the money!

Answer (score 0):

There is small issue in the iOS renderer code try using

```
this.Control.Transform = transform;
```

instead of

```
this.Transform = transform;
```

Comment: I tried the same but this happened http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391200/xamarin-forms-progressbar-height-issue-in-ios

Comment: Try the code I shared on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391200/xamarin-forms-progressbar-height-issue-in-ios/43632035#43632035