# Changing height of custom progresssbar not working Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

i tried to change the height of the progressbar in xamarin.forms using PCL.
the solution seems to be like this: [Xamarin forms increase ProgressBar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673893/xamarin-forms-increase-progressbar-height)

on android this is working fine, but on iOS its not working.
any advice?

**the color and corner radius change is working!**

my code:

```
using ZFBookingAid.iOS;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ProgressBar), typeof(CustomProgressBarRenderer))]
namespace ZFBookingAid.iOS
{
    public class CustomProgressBarRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(
         ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.ProgressTintColor = Color.FromRgb(213, 176, 118).ToUIColor();// This changes the color of the progress


            Control.TrackTintColor = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255).ToUIColor(); //color where is "no progress"

        }



        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();

            var X = 0.5f;
            var Y = 30.0f;

            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(X, Y);
            Control.Transform = transform;
            this.ClipsToBounds = true;
            this.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            this.Layer.CornerRadius = 5; // This is for rounded corners.

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            base.LayoutSubviews();
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(1.2f, 2.5f);
            transform.TransformSize(this.Frame.Size);
            this.Transform = transform;
            this.ClipsToBounds = true;
            this.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;


        }
```

this is how i fixed the height of the progress bar issue.